# Python - Error occuring when trying to access an API more than once

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm programming in school and will soon need to program my final piece. The following program (written in python's programming language) as a program I'm writing simply to practice accessing APIs.
I'm attempting to access the API for a sight based on a game. The idea on the program is to check this API every 30 seconds to check for changes in the data, by storing to sets of data ('baseRank' and 'basePP') as soon as it's running, then comparing this data with new data taken 30 seconds later.
Here is my program:

```
import time

apiKey = '###'
rankDifferences = []
ppDifferences = []
const = True

username = '- Legacy'
url = "https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?u={1}&k={0}".format(apiKey,username)        
import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    stats = json.loads(url.read().decode())
stats = stats[0]

basePP = stats['pp_raw']
print(basePP)
baseRank = stats['pp_rank']
print(baseRank)

while const == True:
    time.sleep(30)
    import urllib.request, json 
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
        check = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    check = check[0]

    rankDifference = baseRank + check['pp_rank']
    ppDifference = basePP + check['pp_raw']
    baseRank = check['pp_raw']
    basePP = check['pp_raw']

    if rankDifference != 0:
        print(rankDifference)

    if ppDifference != 0:
        print(ppDifference)`
```

Please note, where I have written 'apiKey = '###'', I am in fact using a real, working API key, but I've hidden it as the site asks you not to share your api key with others.
Here is the state of the shell after running:

> 5206.55
>
> 12045
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/ethan/Documents/osu API Accessor.py", line 23, in 
>      with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
>    File
>
> "C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", >line 223, in urlopen
>      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>
> File
>
> "C:\Users\ethan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", >line 518, in open
>      protocol = req.type
>
> AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'type'

As you can see, it does print both 'basePP' and 'baseRank', proving that I can access this API. The problem seems to be when I try to access it a second time. To be completely honest, I'm not entirely sure what this error means.. So if you wouldn't mind taking the time to explain and/or help fix this error, it would be greatly appreciated.

Side note: This is my first time using this forum so if I'm doing anything wrong, I'm very sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be when you do:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    stats = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

Your use of the `url` variable is changing it, so that when you try and use it later it doesn't work.

Try something like:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as page:
    stats = json.loads(page.read().decode())
```

and it should be okay.

Comment: Ok I understand the problem now and it fixed it for one iteration of the while loop, so thankyou very much.
When applying the suggested changes, the program waited 30 seconds then did what it was supposed to, however waiting an additional 30 seconds forced the same error. I think I understand the problem now, I'm just not sure how to fix it, so it works everytime the while loop restarts

Comment: Cool, if it helped please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: (sorry, didn't realise clicking return would submit my comment, so had to edit, my bad. Not quite solved yet)

Comment: Did you change the code in your loop too? It needed to be changed in two places.

Comment: ahh, that did it. Thankyou very much!

Comment: I did but I have less than 15 rep so it doesn't display :/